# Do I have to set pruning to archive for supportive full node

Tags: nodes, parity, state-trie-pruning, supernodes

I run a parity node on a server of mine (with a lot of resources and bandwidth) for the sole reason of supporting the network. I don't have any accounts there since my funds are on another machine.

Currently I use the default settings for everything but would like to know if I should change anything, for example set `--pruning` to `archive` to make the node more usefull for others

Comment: I'm tending to answer yes, but I would like to hear a 2nd opinion. Read more on [supernodes](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1156/87) and [pruning modes](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3332/87).

Comment: @5chdn this is my understanding, too.